# Pandas read_excel() fails on importing xlrd

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlrd

I would like to convert multiple `.xls` files stored in my folder to `.csv` format. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import glob
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test'
full_path = os.path.join(path, '*.xls')

    for filename in glob.glob(full_path):

        name_xls = os.path.basename(filename)
        name_csv = name_xls.replace('.xls', '.csv')

        data_xls = pd.read_excel(name_xls)
        data_xls.to_csv(name_csv, sep=';', encoding='ASCI')
```

Even that I downloaded *pandas and xlrd* libraries, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
line 261, in __init__
  **import xlrd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\coverage_code_0\coverage_code_0.py", line
16, in <module>
  data_xls = pd.read_excel(name_xls)   File  
C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py",
line 118, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
line 230, in read_excel
  io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)   File "C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
line 263, in __init__
  raise ImportError(err_msg) ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
```

`import xlrd` doesn't work, when I include that compiler says:

```
No module named 'xlrd'
```

I believe that there is a mistake in my code but I don't know where. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `pip install xlrd` in your cmd to install the library.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\
python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `pip install xlrd` within the same interpreter and virutalenv you have pandas in. In your comment you say that you have `xlrd` installed in `c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32`, but your pandas is in `C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\`. If you don't use a virtualenv, try finding `pip` inside `BundledPython36` folder and run it.

```
C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\...\pip install xlrd
```

If you use a virtualenv, [activate it](http://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/) and simply run `pip install xlrd`.

Comment: that worked! I just simply run pip install xlrd from this directory: C:\Users\XXX\.thonny\BundledPython36\Scripts\

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, you want need this package:

```
def convert_to_csv():
    PATH = path_to_excel
    fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)
    fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.xls' in file]
    for file in fileNames: 
        exl =  pd.read_excel(PATH+file)
        exl.to_csv(PATH+file[:-3]+'csv',sep=';', index=False, header=True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd
    convert_to_csv()
```